# Detect "pure" alphabets in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, vba

Am trying to distinguish the cells containing alphabetic character data from the numeric ones. I have been partly successful using istext() & isnumber(). But when alphanumeric characters come up this logic fails.

My intention is to detect the cells which have only alphabets. Cells containing Numeric or alphanumeric character need to be triggered as false.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`=SUMPRODUCT(0+ISNUMBER(0+MID(A1,ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1))),1)))=0`

You could also use, with `CSE` (CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER), the slightly shorter:

`=COUNT(0+MID(A1,ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1))),1))=0`

The construction being passed to `MID`'s `start_num` parameter here, i.e.:

`ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1)))`

is a `non-volatile` (actually, technically volatile at workbook open only) - and therefore preferable - alternative to e.g.:

`ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)))`

Regards

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Cheers! :-)

Comment: @XORLX Title says "pure alphabets", but won't this formula treat symbols like _-*^ etc. as valid ? Seems like there is no way to restrict to [a-zA-z] in a formula without using `CODE()` ?

Comment: @AmitNaidu Yes. If such characters are possible then this set-up would require amending.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this small *UDF()*:

```
Public Function IsLetters(s As String) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long

    IsLetters = False
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        If Not Mid(s, i, 1) Like "[a-zA-Z]" Then Exit Function
    Next i
    IsLetters = True
End Function
```

[image]

*NOTE:*

The space character will also yield **FALSE**

Answer (score 2):

You can:

```
IsAlpha = len(s) > 0 and not s like "*[!A-Za-z]*"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid macros and want to use it for validation, or in a Conditional Formatting rule to mark invalid cells, then a non-vba formula is nice to have.

The only way I have found so far to do this without messy `CODE()` functions and ASCII values is to use an array formula (press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER) with `SEARCH()` like this:

`IsPureAlpha :`

```
=MIN(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1),"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"))))=1
```

**Explanation:**

- Split the string in cell A1 into individual characters using the `MID` function.
- `SEARCH()` (case-insensitive) for each character in the allowable [a-zA-Z] range.
- Convert the search results array to boolean, and then to binary using the `--` double unary minus trick.
- If any disallowed character was present, the search results array would have a 0. Otherwise for a valid PureAlpha string the entire array would be 1s. The `MIN()` will detect any 0 in the array.

Answer (score 0):

This is another way that might be simpler to use:

```
=COUNT(FIND({"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q",
             "r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"},A1))>0
```